# Forward a multipart data

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to write a service where user will upload file. Two servers are involved.

microservice-1 is accessed by public.
microservice-2 is another service run behind the network.

User upload a file to microservice-1. In springboot, we can accept Multipart as file and store the file to server. But, I want to push the multipart to microservice-2 and microserive-2 will handle this. I wonder if there any valid solution for this. Expectation is server 2 will not store this file.

Unfortunately, no code to attach